# How can I determine if a String is non-null and not only whitespace in Groovy?

Tags: string, groovy, whitespace

Groovy adds the `isAllWhitespace()` method to Strings, which is great, but there doesn't seem to be a *good* way of determining if a String has something other than *just* white space in it.

The best I've been able to come up with is:

```
myString && !myString.allWhitespace
```

But that seems too verbose. This seems like such a common thing for validation that there *must* be a simpler way to determine this.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

Another option is

```
if (myString?.trim()) {
  ...
}
```

(using [Groovy Truth for Strings](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_strings))

Comment: myString?.trim() returns a string (or null or blank) instead of the question's which returns a boolean.
I guess it depends how you're using the output, for just an 'if' it's fine.

Comment: or `boolean containsData = myString?.trim()`

Comment: @Steven, Groovy truth says that a null or empty string is false, so you can just wrap it in `()` as well if you need it in a statement that wouldn't already make it a boolean. For example, `def myVal = (myString?.trim())`

Comment: @cdeszaq if you do `def myVal = (myString?.trim())` then `myVal` is either a `String` or `null`, wrapping it in braces doesn't change it to a boolean.  However, if you assign it to a boolean variable or use `(myString?.trim()) as boolean` or (as in my answer) use it in an `if` statement, then as you say it will use the Groovy Truth value of the string (or the null)

Comment: While this works for string, note if it's a number 0 it will fail. Just a point to highlight, if the value is a guaranteed string then it's good

Comment: What if String is "false"?

Comment: `​if ("false") println "that's true too"`

Comment: This is supposed to be the answer, but without understanding how this actually works (i.e. what is considered `true` in Groovy) I can't use this. Could you expand the answer explaining _why_ this works in Groovy?

Comment: @MichielHaisma added a link to the documentation

Answer (score 10):

You could add a method to String to make it more semantic:

```
String.metaClass.getNotBlank = { !delegate.allWhitespace }
```

which let's you do:

```
groovy:000> foo = ''
===> 
groovy:000> foo.notBlank
===> false
groovy:000> foo = 'foo'
===> foo
groovy:000> foo.notBlank
===> true
```

Comment: Where would the best place to put the metaClass modification be?

Comment: and what if foo = null ?

Comment: @Bertl that would be a null pointer exception. But if foo is null it doesn't have a class and also wouldn't have the metaClass method.

Comment: Your code is utilizing a double negative and makes the code hard to follow.  It's better to do something like isBlank instead.

Comment: Please don't do something like this for a method this simple unless it is absolutely necessary, no one likes random methods on classes that are specific to your codebase. At the very least, in this case name it getNotAllWhiteSpace() to tie it back to the underlying implementation in this case where you are just effectively renaming and inverting a method that already exists. It isn't that hard to just use !foo.allWhitespace to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

It's works in my project with grails2.1:

```
String str = someObj.getSomeStr()?.trim() ?: "Default value"
```

If someObj.getSomeStr() is null or empty "" -> str = "Default value"
If someObj.getSomeStr() = "someValue" -> str = "someValue"

Answer (score 2):

I find this method to be quick and versatile:

```
static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) { return (str == null || str.allWhitespace) } 

// Then I often use it in this manner
DEF_LOG_PATH = '/my/default/path'
logPath = isNullOrEmpty(log_path) ? DEF_LOG_PATH : log_path
```

I am quite new to using Groovy, though, so I am not sure if there exists a way to make it an actual extension method of the `String` type and this works well enough that I have not bothered to look.